# Add or modify method body CIL code from bytes

Tags: .net-assembly, cil, mono.cecil

I would like to add methods or modify methods body of an assembly.
I have the array of bytes containing the CIL code.

Is there a library that does this job ?

Mono.Cecil does it, but only from the parsed IL code :
(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop) ...). I don't want to create an IL parser. Do you know a solution for it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Only from parsed IL code"? Have you read https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil.Cil/CodeReader.cs ?

Comment: There is no comment in the source code you display and this class is not mentioned in the documentation. What am I supposed to do with this ? –